# Github API: how to check if repository is empty?

Tags: github-api, pygithub

I'm using pygithub3 library to parse user repositories, but from time to time, it crasshes on assertion after failed request. At first I suspected that I have hit rate limit, but soon I realized that I can 100% reproduce assertion on 'empty' repository (see example).

https://github.com/poelzi/vaultfs

How would I go around checking if repository is available?
Simplified code snippet:

```
for repo in gh.repos.list(user=author).all():
   ...
   contributors = repo.list_contributors(user=repo.owner.login, repo=repo.name).all()
```

It works for in 99% cases, but when I run into empty repositories, it crashes and I couldn't find any way to 'detect' it.

Comment: Do you have access to the response status code? If so, you should check if the response code is `204`. If it is so, then the repository is empty. [Here](https://developer.github.com/changes/2014-02-19-repo-contributors-for-empty-repos/) is a blog post about that.

Comment: that's very helpful, will look into that

Comment: Posted an answer. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question under **PyGithub** tag, so below one of possible ways to do it in that library.

```
import github
from github import GithubException

g = github.Github(token)

# or if you are using login and password g = github.Github(login, password)
repo = g.get_repo("poelzi/vaultfs")

try:
    # get repo content from root directory
    repo.get_contents("/")
except GithubException as e:
    print(e.args[1]['message']) # output: This repository is empty.
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this blog post](https://developer.github.com/changes/2014-02-19-repo-contributors-for-empty-repos/), Contributors endpoint response code for empty repositories is `204 No Content`.

Here is some relevant `curl` output:

```
curl -v https://api.github.com/repos/poelzi/vaultfs/stats/contributors 
*   Trying 192.30.252.127...
* Connected to api.github.com (192.30.252.127) port 443 (#0)
* found 187 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* found 758 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
...
< HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
< Server: GitHub.com
< Date: Wed, 28 Oct 2015 20:10:10 GMT
< Status: 204 No Content
...
```

Checking the `pygithub` docs, I saw that this is already built-in:

> #### [Repository.get_stats_contributors()](http://jacquev6.net/PyGithub/v2/reference/classes/Repository.html#PyGithub.Blocking.Repository.Repository.get_stats_contributors)
>
> Calls the [GET /repos/:owner/:repo/stats/contributors](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statistics/#contributors) end point.
>
> This is the only method calling this end point.
>
> This method returns None on empty repositories, and an empty list when stats have not been computed yet.
>
> **Return type**:  None or list of `Repository.StatsContributor`

So, that's being said, you have to check for the return value. If it's none, then the repository is empty.

Comment: upvote for effort, even tho v2 and v3 libraries aren't exactly the same (or not at all same).

Comment: @AoeAoe From what I see, there is no `v3` version of the library. Of course, the GitHub API version is `v3`, but the `PyGithub` version is `v2`.